# Scrapy how to update image URL if current image url returns 404

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I need to change the image link in case if current image URLS return 404 code
I have implemented own pipeline by extending FilesPipeline.

I have supposed the method `media_failed` will be called it we got 404 code, but it didn't happen.

in the method `item_completed` I see that `results` for failed URL contains the following info

<class 'tuple'>: (False, <twisted.python.failure.Failure scrapy.pipelines.files.FileException: download-error>)

in this case I have to update origin image link and retry downloading

I see the following info in logs:

```
[scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (code: 404): Error downloading file from <GET https://any_dummy_link.jpg> referred in <None>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request the image URL. If response.status is 404 you can handle it differently.